# Looking to update existing records in one statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im trying to update a list of hosts in a single query.

something like ...

```
INSERT INTO
  hosts ('address', 'display_name') 
VALUES ([['192.168.0.1', 'localhost', '...more'], ['192.168.0.2', 'localhost2', '...more']]);
WHERE host.address = ['192.168.0.1','192.168.0.2', ... ]
```

but Im not really sure how to do this?

I'd like to force update on 10k records at one time.

Comment: To perform a bulk INSERT, you can use the COPY command (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html), but I'm not sure what it is you are trying to accomplish. Is your current insert query not working? Are you looking for a faster insert? Do you want something that looks more elegant? Are you concerned over transaction atomicity?

Comment: Your intention is not clear. Do you want UPDATE or INSERT?

Comment: `insert` creates **new** rows. To change (update) _existing_ ones, use `update`

Comment: I have a data push where 10k records send updates, but there are nested elements. I currently have this ported to a background job, but it enqueues each one individually and it makes it quite slow. 

Im looking for a way to update multiple records with different values all in one query

Comment: So 10k parent records create 10k statements + 10k^n child statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to be mixing up `INSERT` and `UPDATE`. If you want to `INSERT`, it's easy. It's just a comma-separated list of tuples:

```
INSERT INTO hosts ('address', 'display_name') VALUES
('192.168.0.1', 'localhost1'),
-- etc.
('192.168.0.2', 'localhost2')
;
```

For `UPDATE`, assuming you can treat `address` as a primary key, you could pass the same big list of values and join to it, like this:

```
UPDATE hosts
SET display_name = x.n
FROM (VALUES
  ('192.168.0.1', 'localhost1'),
  -- etc.
  ('192.168.0.2', 'localhost2')
) x(ip, n)
WHERE hosts.address = x.ip
;
```

If you are running Postgres 9.5, you could also use the new `ON CONFLICT` feature to do a try-to-insert-and-if-not-then-update.

Answer (score 0):

The insert don't have where condition

```
INSERT INTO
hosts ('address', 'display_name') 
VALUES ([['192.168.0.1', 'localhost', '...more'], ['192.168.0.2',
      'localhost2', '...more']]);
```

for update you should use

```
Update HOSTS
SET display_name = concat('local_host' , spli_part(address, '.',4));
 where address  in ('192.168.0.1','192.168.0.2', .....)
```